# C# Create xml from Scratch

Tags: xml, linq

I know this is probably an easy question, but im having trouble just creating an xml file that will only create its root

i Have the following code but it doesnt work

```
        XDocument products = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
      new XElement("Users",

      )
    );
        products.Save("hello.xml");
```

Comment: after running the program it should create an xml that looks like
<Users>
</Users>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save *some where* in your disk:

```
 XDocument products = new XDocument(
                 new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
                 new XElement("Users"));

products.Save("c:\\hello.xml");
```

**Edit:**

To save in current directory:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hello.xml");
products.Save(path);
```

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez: what do you mean the same directory? which directory?

Comment: products.Save(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\hello.xml");

Comment: im just getting <Users />
is that ok?
i want <Users> 
       </Users>

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez: You can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

Comment: the same directory where the executable is at

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez: it is still okay, they are the same

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after "Users"

Comment: This is a comment - not an answer!

Comment: Why? That's the problem he's experiencing, I took his code and tested it and it's not working because of that. If this is not an answer, then this is not a question either.

Comment: It's an easy question - your answer is true but not a solution for the question.

Comment: The question was very generic ("it doesn't work") so I just thought that was the problem, hence my answer.